# equal indentation for fixed div with height 100%

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, indentation

I have a problem.
I need equal indentation for .gallery-window bottom, left, top, right - each 20px.

```
<div id="gallery-popup">
<div class="shade"></div>
    <div class="gallery-window">
        <div class="gallery-description-container">
            <div class="close"></div>
            <h5>Кухня</h5>
            <p>Автор: <a href="#">janlight</a></p>
            <p>Дата публикации: <time datetime="2014-05-30">30 мая 2014</time></p>
            <div class="like-and-fav">
                <a href="#" class="main-topic-like"><span></span>27</a>
                <a href="#" class="main-topic-fav"><span>Добавить в избранное</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-like">
                <a href="#" class="main-topic-twit"><span></span>14</a>
                <a href="#" class="main-topic-fb"><span></span>59</a>
                <a href="#" class="main-topic-vk"><span></span>8</a>
                <a href="#" class="main-topic-google"><span></span>4</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-img-container">
            <div class="gallery-img-wrapper">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/2200x1200" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-prev-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="prev-gallery"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-next-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="next-gallery"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- gallery-window -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7hqdN/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `fixed` or `absolute` element, you can use coordonate to size your elements.

If you set coordonates to `20px` from borders of window you get what you look for : http://jsfiddle.net/7hqdN/2/

```
.gallery-window {
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    bottom:20px;
    right:20px;
    position: fixed;
    }
```